# Branch points of $\arccos (z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am reading a [text](http://www1.spms.ntu.edu.sg/~ydchong/teaching/07_branch_cuts.pdf) on branch points and branch cuts, and one of the exercises asks me to find the possible values of $\arccos (z)$ at $z = i$.

To do this, I understand that I should find the branch points of $\arccos (z)$, assign branch cuts, and then evaluate the function at $i$ for each branch. I see on Wikipedia that the branch points should be at $z = \pm 1$. I also see that the branch cuts extend to $\pm \infty$ on the real line, which seems to imply that $z = \pm \infty$ are also branch points, right?

I am having trouble squaring this with the instructions for finding branch points given in the text. Namely:

> In most of the examples that we will encounter, the multivaluedness arises ultimately from the complex logarithm, and in such cases the branch points are the values of $z$ such that the input to the logarithm is $0$ or $\infty$.

Following along with Wikipedia's derivation of the logarithmic form of $\arcsin (z)$, I have shown that

$$\arccos(z) = -i \ln\left(z \pm \sqrt{z^2 -1}\right)$$

Since the branch points of $\ln(w)$ are at $0$ and $\infty$, I tried

$$\begin{align}
z + \sqrt{z^2 -1} & = 0 \\
\implies z^2 & = z^2 -1& \text{never} \\\\
z - \sqrt{z^2 -1} & = 0 \\
\implies z^2 & = z^2 -1& \text{never} \\\\
z + \sqrt{z^2 -1} & \to \infty & \text{in the limit as }z\to\infty\\\\
z - \sqrt{z^2 -1} & \to \infty & \text{never(?)}
\end{align}$$

(I put a question mark on the last one because the expression will go to $-\infty$ in the limit as $z\to-\infty$. Is this also considered an "infinity" in the sense that it is a branch point of complex $ln$?)

This seems to suggest that the only branch point of $\arccos(z)$ is $+\infty$, which I know is not true.

Meanwhile, if I plug in $z=\pm 1$ into the logarithmic expression for $\arccos(z)$, I get

$$\begin{align}
\arccos(1)
&= -i\ln(1 \pm 0) \\
&= -i\ln(e^{2\pi i n}), & n \in \mathbb{Z} \\
&= -i(1+ 2\pi i n), & n \in \mathbb{Z} \\
&= 2\pi n - i, & n \in \mathbb{Z} \\\\
\arccos(-1)
&= -i\ln(-1 \pm 0) \\
&= -i\ln(e^\pi e^{2\pi i n}), & n \in \mathbb{Z} \\
&= -i(\pi+ 2\pi i n), & n \in \mathbb{Z} \\
&= 2\pi n - i \pi, & n \in \mathbb{Z} \\\\
\end{align}$$

In both cases, $\arccos(z)$ is multiple-valued, so $z=\pm 1$ does not seem like a branch point for this function.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Good question.... Is it possible that the branching happens where the formula for $\arccos$ switches from $-i \ln\left(z + \sqrt{z^2 -1}\right)$ to $-i \ln\left(z -\sqrt{z^2 -1}\right)$?

Comment: $\arccos(1) = -i \ln e^{2\pi i n} = 2\pi n$ and

$\arccos(-1) = -i \ln e^{(2n+1)\pi i} = (2n+1)\pi$. It appears all points $(-1,1)$ are multivalued, so a branch cut along $(-1,1)$ would work

Comment: @sku The text defines a branch point as "a point $z$ where the multi-valued operation gives an unambiguous answer, with different branches giving the same output." If $z= \pm 1$ are multivalued, how can they be branch points? And aren't all points *everywhere* multivalued in this function?

Comment: That definition of a branch point does not work in general. $\sqrt z + \sqrt {z - 1}$ takes two different values at $z = 0$, but $z = 0$ is a branch point.

For $\arccos$, you also need to consider where the argument of the square root is zero. That will give you two algebraic branch points. $\infty$ is a logarithmic branch point. As expected, you get the general form of the solution of $\cos w = z$. To answer the original question, you can just solve $\cos w = i$ (with some arbitrary choice of $\arccos i$).